# Aggregate roots vs aggregates in a hierarchical system

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I've been doing a lot of research on DDD and have been stumbling a bit on the concept of Aggregates vs Aggregate Roots.

Say I'm trying to model a space game that exists in a strict hierarchy, with a `Sector` Entity that wraps around everything contained within it. It can have a collection of `PlanetarySystem`, each of those can have a collection of `Star`, the stars can have a collection of `Planet` which themselves can have a collection of `Moon`

I want all of these objects to either be associated with that `Sector`, situated nicely in the hierarchy, but it can also be associated with no sector. Each item can have a 0 or 1 relationship with the object in the hierarchy above it... floating in the ether if need be. I want to be able to delete a `Planet` without deleting all the `Moon` entities it has, but it can be done optionally.

Am I wrong to think that these should each be their own Aggregate Root in this scenario, with references to the Aggregate Root instances that they contain? Or should the `Sector` be the actual Aggregate Root, orchestrating everything as the object at the top of the hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An aggregate root should never contain a reference to another aggregate root.  You should use either an id to reference an associated aggregate or a value object containing the id and some other pertinent data.

Anything that is *floating in the ether* would be an aggregate root since it has a lifecycle of its own.

I reckon the hierarchy should just work in a unidirectional manner as far as the domain is concerned.  If you need to query lower level items based on higher level containment then you either need joins or need to denormalize the relevant higher level identifiers/data into the lower level items.

My advice would be to attempt to keep any aggregate a single level deep but if that isn't practical then try something deeper but it gets unwieldy rather quickly.

Comment: So it might be a better strategy then for me to define my objects(as described above) as Aggregate Roots, but any references should be as Ids only (ideally Value Objects representing those Ids).

So would I then coordinate the relationships between these objects in a Domain Service or something?

Comment: You should attempt to place as much behaviour as possible in your aggregate roots.  If a method does not fit on a particular aggregate root then you are probably making use of more than one aggregate root instance to effect the behaviour and a domain service would be appropriate.  If coordinating the relationships fits into the domain service definition then by all means use them.  However, one should be judicious about the use of domain services as overuse may leave your domain somewhat anemic.

Answer (score 1):

Remember something can be an Aggregate in one use case and an Aggregate Root in another.  If your use case is AddPlanetarySystemToSector, then Sector is your Aggregate Root. If your use case is AddMoonToPlanet, then Planet is the AR.

The difference is that an AR should not be saved unless it and all Aggregates it owns satisfy all business rules.  The higher level your AR, the more business rules you must test and satisfy.  Therefore your use cases should be a specific as possible and target the proper AR.

If this poses problems, a work around is to have ARs own value objects instead of aggregates.  So a Sector would own PlanetarySystemVOs.  If the Sector needs to modify a PlanetarySystem, it can launch a PlanetarySystem use case that performs the proper action.

Comment: So the Aggregate Root is dynamic, based on the use case? I hadn't read this anywhere. Why do so many of the examples I see have the Entity implement an IAggregateRoot interface if it's dependent upon the use case?